# AWS Pricing for upgrading reserved instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have bought a AWS EC2 Instance a while ago and now our app has became huge we need a better server and we are planning to upgrade the server, if we are going to upgrade an reserved instance, will they charge only extra amount needed to upgrade or full amount of the new reserved one.

Any help is greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you buy a reserved instance, you have locked yourself into the contract, whether it be 1 or 3 years. In return for lower pricing, you agreed to keep the server for that term.

If it's a light or medium duty instance, you can simply stop using it and stop accruing hourly/daily charges - a heavy instance (which I am guessing is what you have), gets billed 24x7 whether you use it or not.

So, in one sense you are 'stuck' with it, but you do have the option of selling your unused instance 'used' here: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/purchasing-options/reserved-instances/marketplace/

You probably will be able to get back at least some of your costs - I have bought several hear myself when I need a heavy/reserved instance, but didn't want to lock myself into a three year contract.

Comment: Actually the thing is i dont want my money back. i am going upgrade mu m1.small to m1.xlarge. Will the upfront money i paid be adjusted for the upgrade or do i have to pay it in full for upgrading from small to xlarge

Comment: You have to buy a new instance in full - but you might be able to sell your old instance after-the-fact to help cover the cost.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your situation, you may be able to [modify your RI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ri-modifying.html).
E.g. convert two `m1.small` to one `m1.medium`.

Comment: Actually the thing is i dont want my money back. i am going upgrade mu m1.small to m1.xlarge. Will the upfront money i paid be adjusted for the upgrade or do i have to pay it in full for upgrading from small to xlarge

Comment: if you have only one m1.small - you cannot do anything with it. the best you can do is sell it on RI marketplace and create a new reservation. Or think of a way to use this instance for something else.